# Java-Storing characters of a string in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception

```
    for (int j = 0; j <= l - 1; j++) 
   { char c1 = str.charAt(j);
      n[j] = c1;
   }
//It is showing error-arrayIndexoutofbounds
```

'str' is an inputted string and 'l' is the length of the string str.
I have to store all its character in an array and the array 'n' is of char type 
I have tried to store it by for loop but its showing error . Please help me out. 
Just remove that equal to sign in ur loop it will only be less than

Comment: How did you declare ``n``?

Comment: can you post full code

Comment: please provie an [mcve]

Comment: array have a fixed length that is determined when you create it, that exception means that you're trying to put too many elements. check the size of n.

Comment: @Mritunjay I have tried to post the full code but it was showing the problem of indentation . I tried to correct it but could not so posted this part only .Can you please tell me how to post the full code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array `n` should be declared as:

```
char[] n = new char[str.length()];
```

That creates an array with the exact size needed to put all your `String`'s characters in it.

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when you access an illegal index of the array, in this case I suspect your array is smaller than the length of the `String`.

Comment: Or, alternatively, `char[] n = new char[l]`. (<- that's a lower-case `L`, not the digit "one")

Comment: **Please note**: Strings in Java are UTF-16 Unicode. Because Unicode contains more than 65536 characters, this means some characters require 2 16-bit symbols to encode. For this reason, Oracle [recommends against](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/design.html) using `char` types to represent character arrays (yes it's too bad but Unicode outgrew 16-bit only after Java already had comitted to it). Instead, make an array of `int` and use `codePointAt` and `codePointCount` etc.

Answer (score 4):

No need to create and fill such an array manually, there is a built-in method [`String.toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) that does the job for you:

```
n = str.toCharArray()
```

Comment: No worries. You can replace the whole for-loop with the one line from my answer - it does the same thing.

Comment: how can I post the full code it has some other errors also(not syntax) that I want to get clear

Comment: You can edit your original question by clicking on "edit" (right under your question), but perhaps consider just writing a new question if you have other issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert string into character array then string class already have method called toCharArray().

```
String str = "StackOverflow";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

then if you want to check content of array print it.

```
for(int i = 0;i < charArray.length ; i++) {
     System.out.print(" " + charArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: To print an array, it's preferable to use the following piece of code: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray));`

Comment: @Olivier Agreed. Other than that, this answer is exactly the same as mine.